# source title and url not displayed in Google calendar when using calendar api

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

Using Google Calendar's api with python, I added an event with a source url. It doesn't display the title of the source url on the web and it doesn't display the url at all on the google calendar's android app. Is there an issue with my code? Or, is there a bug in google calendar?

[image: event on web version] [image]

This is the source parameter I used:

```
'source': {
    'url': 'https://www.nps.gov/grte/planyourvisit/bcres.htm',
    'title': 'NPS Permit website'
  },
```

Here is my entire code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from datetime import date, timedelta
import datetime
import calendar
import httplib2
import os
from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage

try:
  import argparse
  flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
flags = None

def get_credentials():
  home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
  credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
  if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
    os.makedirs(credential_dir)
  credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                               'calendar-python-quickstart.json')

  store = Storage(credential_path)
  credentials = store.get()
  if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
    flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
    if flags:
      credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
    else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
      credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
    print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
  return credentials

def main():  
  credentials = get_credentials()
  http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
  service = discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)

  cal_id  = 'h44h6fptkt81d36n4rapm9snrs@group.calendar.google.com'

  cal_body = {
    'start': {
      'date': '2018-01-03',
      'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
    },
    'end': {
      'date': '2018-01-03',
      'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
    },
    'summary': 'Event Title',
    'source': {
      'url': 'https://www.nps.gov/grte/planyourvisit/bcres.htm',
      'title': 'NPS Permit website'
    }, 
    'recurrence': ['RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=1;BYSETPOS=1;BYDAY=WE']
  }

  event = service.events().insert(calendarId=cal_id,body=cal_body ).execute()
  print(cal_body)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this looks like a bug in Google Calendar API. You can find this bug in the issue tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73334552

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)